# Axler Example 3.82: Parallel affine subsets

Tags: linear-algebra

In Example 3.82 of Axler's book, he gives an example of parallel affine subsets. I'm fine with his example in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but confused with his example in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It reads as follows. .

> If $U = \{(x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$, then the affine subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ parallel to $U$ are the planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are parallel to the $xy$-plane $U$ in the usual sense. **Important:** With the definition of parallel given in 3.81, no line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is considered to be an affine subset that is parallel to the plane $U$.

I'm trying to prove these two claims, but I'm having trouble tying this back to the definition. All affine subsets of $U$ are of the form $v + U$ for some $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$. If $v = (a,b,c)$ is fixed, these subsets have the form
$$
v + U = \{(a + x, b + y, c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3\}. 
$$
If I am not mistaken, a plane parallel to the $xy$-plane is of the form $z = k$ for some constant $k \neq 0$, which I haven't much trouble visualizing. I can't figure out how the set I wrote down above has this form. I'm also not sure how to prove his comment on lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I believe line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ have the form
$$
\ell = (a,b,c) + t(e,f,g)
$$
for some scalar $t$ where $(a,b,c)$ and $(e,f,g)$ are fixed. If I am not mistaken, this is equivalent to a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I don't see a relationship to the example of this affine subset, though.

I'd greatly appreciate some help in understanding this.